# IOS Application Name

Tags: ios, itunes, submission

I have a strange problem with my application name: my project is called "something - somenumber" (with the **dash**).

For the submission, the App name I've chosen is without tje dash, infact, in the iTunes Store I can see the name without it.

But when I download my approved App, the name is with the dash..

Have you ever heard something similar???
Is this a problem with the new SDK and IOS version?
Now the name has to coincide with project name???

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

By default, the `Bundle display name` in the `Info.plist` of iOS apps is `${PRODUCT_NAME}`. `${PRODUCT_NAME}`, by default, is the same as the project name, which in your case has a dash. The `Bundle display name` is the text that gets displayed under your app's icon in the device's home screen. This could be the reason why you can see the dash when you download the app.

Comment: I don't know, perhaps I didn't understand you, but I'm pretty sure I've named my projects with many different names (apart from the dash, I can see right know on my desktop 2 Apps whose project name don't coincide with the final App name) but the App name in iTunes Store is always the one I choose during the submission despite of the project name.

Comment: @Miwi What I am saying is not really related to submission. Can you check in your app's build settings what the `Product Name` is?

Comment: ok, so If I look in the Info.plist I can see that for the key "Bundle display name" is "${PRODUCT_NAME}" and the same is for  "Bundle name".. is it correct, isn't?

Comment: @Miwi That will work. Those are default values. Can you check in your project's `Build Settings` what the `Product Name` is? (This is not the same as the Info.plist. Click your project on the Project Navigator then click Build Settings. A reference link on how to view Build Settings is http://meandmark.com/blog/2011/03/xcode-4-accessing-build-settings/)

Comment: (great explanation!) that value is **with the dash** that is the one is see when I download the app! that should be the problem! So that is the value that has to coincide with the app name!??

Comment: If you want all dashes to be removed, wherever they may appear in iOS, yes. If you just want the name in the home screen, you can change just the `Bundle display name`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17219/discussion-between-miwi-and-neilvillareal)

Comment: So I have to remove the variable ${PRODUCT_NAME} and put the name I want to display. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should change the CFBundleDisplayName in the apps Info plist file. This value is what the iOS spring board uses underneath each app. This can also be localised.

**.bundle identifier is for the provisioning profile.**

Comment: The value for CFBundleDisplayName is ${PRODUCT_NAME}.. There's something I don't get..